# iOS Bundling failed Unable to resolve module crypto React Native

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, npm, package.json

I am currently working on an a React Native App. Whenever I start the App on the smartphone using the expo Go App I get the error:

```
iOS Bundling failed 1795ms
Unable to resolve module crypto from /home/kaido/Documents/nonya/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js: crypto could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
> 1 | var Crypto           = require('crypto');
    |                                 ^
  2 | var Events           = require('events');
  3 | var Net              = require('net');
  4 | var tls              = require('tls');
```

This is my package.json file

```
 {
      "name": "myapp",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.2",
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
        "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
        "events": "^3.3.0",
        "expo": "~46.0.16",
        "expo-crypto": "~11.0.0",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "mysql": "^2.18.1",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.11",
        "react": "18.0.0",
        "react-native": "0.69.6",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.5.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
        "react-native-snap-carousel": "3.9.1",
        "url": "^0.11.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
      },
      "private": true
    }
```

I have been trying to solve the error for days but no success.
Could anyone help me out?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem.
Instead of fetching the data directly from the database, I wrote an API in Node, ran it separately, and then fetched what I required from the database through an endpoint in the server.

Comment: Could you share how this fixed 

"iOS Bundling failed 50ms
Unable to resolve "crypto-js/sha256"